# Curses::UI - Listbox: Note: The "Can't use string ("Gino.Francescutti@xx")" Doesn't contain the full email, only partial

Tags: perl, listbox, hashtable, curses

Most of the information is here: http://pastebin.com/VE6dhUkf

But the general error is:

```
Odd number of elements in hash assignment at /usr/share/perl5/Curses/UI/Container.pm line 72.
Can't use string ("Gino.Francescutti@xx") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at /usr/share/perl5/Curses/UI/Listbox.pm line 264.
```

Note: The "Can't use string ("Gino.Francescutti@xx")" Doesn't contain the full email, only partial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're mixing up your arrays and array-refs. You have this:

```
my $listbox; $listbox = $win1->add(
    'list',
    'Listbox',
    -values => @marray,
    -lables => $lhash,
    -onchange => sub { exit($_[0]->get)}
);
```

Notice the `-values => @marray`? That should be `-values => \@marray`. From the [fine manual](http://search.cpan.org/~mdxi/Curses-UI-0.9609/lib/Curses/UI/Listbox.pm#SYNOPSIS):

```
my $listbox = $win->add(
    'mylistbox', 'Listbox',
    -values    => [1, 2, 3],
    #...
);
```

That mixup doesn't directly point to your error message but it could sufficiently mess up what `$win->add` is seeing and confuse it enough to cause the error you're seeing as a side effect.